# Accessibility permission popup shown again when run Appium test

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, accessibility

I'm automating android application which requires Accessibility permission. Manually enabled Accessibility before my test run.

Now when i start Appium test, getting accessibility popup again when after launching my app. [for each button access via appium shows accessibility permission popup again]

Appium: 1.6.2
OEM: Samsung
OS: Android 7.1.1

thanks in advance. Workaround also needed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set noReset in the Desired Capabilities.

Java:

```
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
```

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/